# Fill in a field without label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, textfield

I have a text field like this :

```rb
<%= form_for(ownership, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_field :confirm, value: nil, title: t('label.transaction.confirmation.code') %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :start_date, value: Time.now %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit t('button.ownership.take.confirmation'), class: "btn btn-small"%>
<% end %>
```

And I want to fill in the text field with rspec :

```rb
fill_in t('label.transaction.confirmation.code'), with: "something"
```

But it doesn't work because the rspec don't recognize the title tag in order to fill in the text field :

```rb
Failure/Error: fill_in t('label.transaction.confirmation.code'), with: confirmation_code
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Code de confirmation"
```

Do you know a way to fill in the text field with rspec without adding a label ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `fill_in` method's first argument must be a css selection.  for example: `#id`, `li`, `.class`.

So you can change `t('label.transaction.confirmation.code')`

to the text field `id` or `[title='#{t('label.transaction.confirmation.code')}']`

e.g.

```
<input id="conf_code">
fill_in 'conf_code', with: 'something'
```

Comment: OK, the rendered html created a specific id for my text field : `<input id="transaction_confirm" type="text" name="transaction[confirm]">`. So I replaced `t('label.transaction.confirmation.code')` by `"transaction_confirm"` in my test file and it worked !